# How do I find the parent array index for an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an output like

```
Array
(
    [2014-04-29] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => remindar_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => reminder
                )

        )

    [2014-04-22] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

        )

    [2014-04-21] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => travel_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => travel
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => invite.jpg
                    [category_slug] => invite
                )

        )

    [2014-04-19] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

        )

    [2014-04-23] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => travel_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => travel
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => restaurants_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => restaurants
                )

        )

    [2014-04-10] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

        )

    [2014-04-20] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

        )

    [2014-04-15] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => photo_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => photos
                )

        )

    [2014-04-16] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => photo_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => photos
                )

        )

    [2014-05-01] => Array
        (
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => event_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => events
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [2014-04-29] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => remindar_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => reminder
                )

        )

    [2014-04-22] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

        )

    [2014-04-21] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => travel_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => travel
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => invite.jpg
                    [category_slug] => invite
                )

        )

    [2014-04-19] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

        )

    [2014-04-23] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => travel_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => travel
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => restaurants_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => restaurants
                )

        )

    [2014-04-10] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

        )

    [2014-04-20] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

        )

    [2014-04-15] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => photo_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => photos
                )

        )

    [2014-04-16] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => photo_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => photos
                )

        )



)
Array
(
    [2014-04-29] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => remindar_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => reminder
                )

        )

    [2014-04-22] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

        )

    [2014-04-21] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => travel_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => travel
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => invite.jpg
                    [category_slug] => invite
                )

        )

    [2014-04-19] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

        )

    [2014-04-23] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => shopping_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => shopping
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => travel_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => travel
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [cal_icon] => restaurants_images.jpg
                    [category_slug] => restaurants
                )

        )
```

If I have  `[category_slug] => travel` then I want to get   `all the date index that belongs to`[category_slug] => travel`
Hey i am getting correct output but it is not breaking it is coming multiple time.Please help me.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $date => $entries) {
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        if ($entry['category_slug'] == 'shopping') {
            echo $date; // or return, or whatever
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `foreach`

```
$keyword = 'shopping';
foreach ($arr1 as $k=>$arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $k2=>$arr2)
    {
        if($arr2['category_slug']==$keyword)
        {
            echo $k;
            //break; //<--- Uncommented since you need all the entries
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://eval.in/140038)</kbd>

Comment: Hey i am getting correct output but it is not breaking it is coming multiple time. How to break it.The value is not coming fix times.It can vary.

Comment: Use the `break` as shown in the code. Did you check the demo ?

Comment: yeah i have checked demo. i want all date that is in loop not only one and i am getting all date but multiple times.i have also used break.please help me

Comment: @Muk, All date ? Can you explain a bit more clearer , also if possible tell us what is your expected output and post the new array too.

Comment: i have added plz see that.

Comment: If you want all of them , then remove the `break;` from the code and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// $ARR_INPUT is your array

$keyword_search = "shopping";
$key_to_search = "category_slug";

$flag = 0;
$output = "";
foreach($ARR_INPUT as $key1=>$arr1)
{
    foreach($arr1 as $key2=>$arr2)
    {
        if($arr2[$key_to_search] == $keyword_search)
        {
            $output = $key1;
            $flag = 1; 
            break;
        }
    }
    if($flag==1)
    {   
        break;
    }
}

echo "Output : ".$key1;
```